# With Python, how can I ensure that compression of a folder takes place within a particular folder?

Tags: python, file, zip

I have been able to zip the contents of my folder. But I would like the zipped file to remain in the folder that was just compressed. For example, I've zipped a folder called test in my C: drive. But I would like my "test.zip" file to be contained in C:\test. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

***clarification of question with code example:***

Someone kindly pointed out that my question is confusing, but for a python newbie a lot of things are confusing :) - my advance apologies if this question is too basic or the answer is obvious. I don't know how I can ensure that the resulting zip file is inside the folder that has been zipped. In other words, I would like the zip process to take place in 'basedir.' That way the user does not waste time searching for it somewhere on the C drive.

```
    def zip_folder(basedir, zip_file):
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
        print "zipping files:"
        for fn in filenames:
        print fn
        absfn = os.path.join(dirpath, fn)
        z.write(absfn)
        z.close
```

Comment: You are not making much sense. It sounds like you just need to create your zip file in the right place using a file path instead of just a file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you pass as zip_file to your function will be the file that the ZipFile object will write to. So if you pass it a full path, then it will be put there. If you pass it just a filename, then it will be written to that filename under the current working path. It sounds like you just need to make sure that zip_file is an absolute path.